# Why is java not generating pdf files after compiling (Clean and build) but it is generating from within netbeans (run)?

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I have a java project that is supposed to generate pdf reports. It does generate the report when I right click on the project and run, but after I compile the project (clean and build) the report generated is 0 bytes, which cannot open. Where am I going wrong?
netbeans version 20 (and 19)
jdk 11 in project properties
Source/Binary/Format JDK8 (with JDK 11, jar file generated is not opening)
Profile: Full JRE

```
 try {
            float columnWidths[] = {50f, 200f, 100f, 200f, 200f, 100f, 200f, 200f};
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("PdfDocumen2t.pdf");//How I define the file name
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(writer);
            document.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            document.addNewPage();
 ............................}
```

When I run from netbeans (run project) the pdfdocumen2t.pdf is good, with all contents 195kb

When I run jar file generated after clean and build, and proceed to generate the report, it is generated with 0 bytes, cannot open

Comment: Did you close your PDFWriter?  Did you make a failure very clear to the person running the program, by propagating exceptions or at least printing their stack traces?

Comment: It might be a lot of reasons. Are you using the same maven settings in Netbeans as in your command prompt? Find the actual command lines used in each case and inspect them for relevant differences.

Comment: Have you defined a place to store your file? Does this file is appearing in some folder? Maybe you don't provide permissions to edit file... There might be a dozen of reasons

Comment: You show a `try` - is there a corresponding `catch`? And do you report exceptions or errors caught?

Comment: Thank you.
During clean and building, folders are being distorted and path to an image I had embeded on pdf was 'Unavailable', printing stacktrace to a text file has helped me Identify the problem....

Thank you